# Can't get audio oscillator to drive amplifier

Tags: amplifier, oscillator

I’ve put together a simple oscillator to try and test some simple audio amplifiers with. It works quite happily without any amplifier.

[image: simple audio oscillator]

When I connected it to an amplifier I threw together on my breadboard, it produced no sound and one of the transistors on the oscillator exploded.

[image: amplifier circuit which works in Falstad]

I thought maybe the input impedance of the amplifier was too low or the output impedance of the oscillator was too high, so I tried putting an emitter follower and a variety of different coupling capacitors in Falstad and using slightly different amplifier and oscillator designs, but whatever I do the audio oscillator won't start to oscillate. I’ve been connecting it as if the amplifier is the speaker for the oscillator.

How I’ve connected them:

[image]

With an emitter follower:

[image]

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I want a way to test to see if simple amplifiers I’ve thrown together are working (one of them broke the jack on my phone.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oscillator already is designed to drive a speaker directly, with the speaker acting not only as a speaker, but as an inductor and resistance of the oscillating circuit. It won't work and oscillate if you remove the speaker and replace it with something that does not resemble a speaker in any way.

If you must use it, you need to have the speaker there, and use the signal on speaker terminals as output.

Answer (score 2):

Your Falstad amplifier schematic was a nightmare to look at, so I drew it normally in an LTspice simulation. I reduced the supply voltage so that little output transistors can be used and changed R2 and R3 to match them. I added an important input resistor R1 but you probably need to increase its resistance. I used a sinewave but your oscillator produces a very distorted squarish waveform.
[image: amplifier]

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see, is that there's no base resistor for the input to your amplifier. Usually a resistor is used to limit the current into the transistor, without it it will be dangerously low. You should include a resistor after the 40Hz input
Also, 40Hz is pretty low. Even if your amplifier can produce this, and that's not an assumption I'd readily make, your speaker might not handle it, and you might not be able to hear it. Yes, 20-20k is the "human" range, but the reality is most folk don't hear that widely. The bottom line is you might want to increase the frequency or at least put your finger on the speaker to double-check.